# how to set the height of the parent that child img can set according to their parent without stretching img on all screens included zoom out

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
.no-padd {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.no-padd01 {
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.sale-div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9;
}

.sale-div02 {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}

.sale-div img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto !important;
  margin: 5px 22px 0px 0px;
}

.sale-div02 img {
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 22px;
}

.sale-div h4 {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.sale-div h4 span {
  color: #cda545;
}

.suit-collection {
  width: 100%;
}

.suit-collection img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.products-inr {
  width: 100%;
}

.products-inr ul li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  min-height: 322px;
}

.products-inr ul li img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.products-sm {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}


/*ul#show-products .products-sm {
            height: 634px;
            position:relative;
     text-align:center;
    }*/

.search-products ul li .products-sm,
.cart-products ul li .products-sm {
  height: 634px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 634px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.search-products ul li .products-sm img,
.cart-products ul li .products-sm img,
.related-products .products-sm img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.related-products .products-sm {
  height: 443px;
  max-width: 443px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.products-sm:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 33px -2px rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 33px -2px rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 33px -2px rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
}

.products-sm:hover .hover-div {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.hover-div {
  background: rgba(212, 180, 104, .8);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0% 0 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
  -o-transform: scale(0.5);
  transform: scale(0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
  display: table;
}

.hover-inr {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.hover-div h4 {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.hover-div h4 a {
  color: #fff;
}

.hover-div h5 {
  font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.hover-div p {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.hover-div p img {
  width: auto !important;
}

.btn {
  padding: 10px 19px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #cda545;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none !important;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.suit-collection {
  position: relative;
  height: 665px;
}

.suit-collection:hover .scnd-hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.scnd-hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30% 0 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
  -o-transform: scale(0.5);
  transform: scale(0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
  z-index: 99;
}

.scnd-hover h3 {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  padding: 128px 78px;
  background: url(../images/left-corner.png) left top no-repeat, url(../images/right-corner.png) right bottom no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
}

.no-margin {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="main-products homepage-products clearfix">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 push-lg-6 push-md-6 no-padd01">
    <div class="suit-collection">
      <a href="/search/65?page=1">
        <span id="box1-img-editor"><img src="/public/images/index_box1.png" alt=""></span>
        <div class="scnd-hover hidden">
          <h3>Sherwani</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 pull-lg-6 pull-md-6 no-padd">
    <div class="products-inr">
      <div class="row">
        <ul>
          <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="products-sm">
              <span id="box8-img-editor"><img src="/public/images/index_box8.png" alt=""></span>
              <div class="hover-div">
                <div class="hover-inr">
                  <h4>
                    <a href="#" id="main_img1_title-text-editor"> </a>
                  </h4>
                  <!-- <h5>Premium Collection</h5>
                                            <p><img src="/public/images/star.png" alt="" /></p> -->
                  <p id="main_img2_title-text-editor">£ </p>
                  <a id="header_cart01-link-editor" class="btn" href="https://www.google.com">+ add to cart</a>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="products-sm">
              <span id="box9-img-editor"><img src="/public/images/index_box9.png" alt=""></span>
              <div class="hover-div">
                <div class="hover-inr">
                  <h4>
                    <a href="#" id="main_img3_title-text-editor"> </a>
                  </h4>
                  <!-- <h5>Premium Collection</h5>
                                                <p><img src="/public/images/star.png" alt="" /></p> -->
                  <p id="main_img4_title-text-editor">£ </p>
                  <a id="header_cart02-link-editor" class="btn" href="https://www.google.com">+ add to cart</a>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="products-sm">
              <span id="box10-img-editor"><img src="/public/images/index_box10.png" alt=""></span>
              <div class="hover-div">
                <div class="hover-inr">
                  <h4>
                    <a href="#" id="main_img5_title-text-editor"> </a>
                  </h4>
                  <!-- <h5>Premium Collection</h5>
                                                <p><img src="/public/images/star.png" alt="" /></p> -->
                  <p id="main_img6_title-text-editor">£ </p>
                  <a id="header_cart03-link-editor" class="btn" href="https://www.google.com"> + add to cart</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="products-sm">
              <span id="box11-img-editor"><img src="/public/images/index_box11.png" alt=""></span>
              <div class="hover-div">
                <div class="hover-inr">
                  <h4>
                    <a href="#" id="main_img7_title-text-editor"> </a>
                  </h4>
                  <!-- <h5>Premium Collection</h5>
                                                <p><img src="/public/images/star.png" alt="" /></p> -->
                  <p id="main_img8_title-text-editor">£ </p>
                  <a id="header_cart04-link-editor" class="btn" href="https://www.google.com"> + add to cart</a>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 no-padd">
    <div class="suit-collection">
      <a href="/search/54?page=1">
        <span id="box2-img-editor"><img src="/public/images/index_box2.png" alt=""></span>
        <div class="scnd-hover hidden">
          <h3>Sherwani</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 no-padd01">
    <div class="products-inr">
      <div class="row no-margin">
        <ul>
          <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="products-sm">
              <span id="box12-img-editor"><img src="/public/images/index_box12.png" alt=""></span>
              <div class="hover-div">
                <div class="hover-inr">
                  <h4>
                    <a href="#" id="main_img9_title-text-editor"> </a>
                  </h4>
                  <!-- <h5>Premium Collection</h5>
                                                <p><img src="/public/images/star.png" alt="" /></p> -->
                  <p id="main_img10_title-text-editor">£ </p>
                  <a id="header_cart05-link-editor" class="btn" href="https://www.google.com"> + add to cart</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="products-sm">
              <span id="box13-img-editor"><img src="/public/images/index_box13.png" alt=""></span>
              <div class="hover-div">
                <div class="hover-inr">
                  <h4>
                    <a href="#" id="main_img11_title-text-editor"> </a>
                  </h4>
                  <!-- <h5>Premium Collection</h5>
                                                <p><img src="/public/images/star.png" alt="" /></p> -->
                  <p id="main_img12_title-text-editor">£ </p>
                  <a id="header_cart06-link-editor" class="btn" href="https://www.google.com"> + add to cart</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="products-sm">
              <span id="box14-img-editor"><img src="/public/images/index_box14.png" alt=""></span>
              <div class="hover-div">
                <div class="hover-inr">
                  <h4>
                    <a href="#" id="main_img13_title-text-editor"> </a>
                  </h4>
                  <!-- <h5>Premium Collection</h5>
                                                <p><img src="/public/images/star.png" alt="" /></p> -->
                  <p id="main_img14_title-text-editor">£ </p>
                  <a id="header_cart07-link-editor" class="btn" href="http://www.google.com"> + add to cart</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="products-sm">
              <span id="box15-img-editor"><img src="/public/images/index_box15.png" alt=""></span>
              <div class="hover-div">
                <div class="hover-inr">
                  <h4>
                    <a href="#" id="main_img15_title-text-editor"> </a>
                  </h4>
                  <!-- <h5>Premium Collection</h5>
                                                <p><img src="/public/images/star.png" alt="" /></p> -->
                  <p id="main_img16_title-text-editor">£ </p>
                  <a id="header_cart08-link-editor" class="btn" href="http://www.google.com"> + add to cart</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 push-lg-6 push-md-6 no-padd01">
    <div class="suit-collection">
      <a href="/search/65?page=1">
        <span id="box3-img-editor"><img src="/public/images/index_box3.png" alt=""></span>
        <div class="scnd-hover hidden">
          <h3>Sherwani</h3>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="sale-div">
                                <img src="/public/images/sale-bg.png" alt="" />
                                <h4>sale up to <span>25% off</span></h4>
                            </div>-->
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 pull-lg-6 pull-md-6 no-padd">
    <div class="products-inr">
      <div class="row">
        <ul>
          <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="products-sm">
              <span id="box16-img-editor"><img src="/public/images/index_box16.png" alt=""></span>
              <div class="hover-div">
                <div class="hover-inr">
                  <h4>
                    <a href="#" id="main_img17_title-text-editor"> </a>
                  </h4>
                  <!-- <h5>Premium Collection</h5>
                                                <p><img src="/public/images/star.png" alt="" /></p> -->
                  <p id="main_img18_title-text-editor">£ </p>
                  <a id="header_cart09-link-editor" class="btn" href="http://www.google.com"> + add to cart</a>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="products-sm">
              <span id="box17-img-editor"><img src="/public/images/index_box17.png" alt=""></span>
              <div class="hover-div">
                <div class="hover-inr">
                  <h4>
                    <a href="#" id="main_img19_title-text-editor"> </a>
                  </h4>
                  <!-- <h5>Premium Collection</h5>
                                                <p><img src="/public/images/star.png" alt="" /></p> -->
                  <p id="main_img20_title-text-editor">£ </p>
                  <a id="header_cart10-link-editor" class="btn" href="http://www.google.com"> + add to cart</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="products-sm">
              <span id="box18-img-editor"><img src="/public/images/index_box18.png" alt=""></span>
              <div class="hover-div">
                <div class="hover-inr">
                  <h4>
                    <a href="#" id="main_img21_title-text-editor"> </a>
                  </h4>
                  <!-- <h5>Premium Collection</h5>
                                                <p><img src="/public/images/star.png" alt="" /></p> -->
                  <p id="main_img22_title-text-editor">£ </p>
                  <a id="header_cart11-link-editor" class="btn" href="http://www.google.com"> + add to cart</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="products-sm">
              <span id="box19-img-editor"><img src="/public/images/index_box19.png" alt=""></span>
              <div class="hover-div">
                <div class="hover-inr">
                  <h4>
                    <a href="#" id="main_img23_title-text-editor"> </a>
                  </h4>
                  <!-- <h5>Premium Collection</h5>
                                            <p><img src="/public/images/star.png" alt="" /></p> -->
                  <p id="main_img24_title-text-editor">£ </p>
                  <a id="header_cart12-link-editor" class="btn" href="http://www.google.com"> + add to cart</a>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 no-padd">
    <div class="suit-collection">
      <a href="/search/54?page=1">
        <span id="box4-img-editor"><img src="/public/images/index_box4.png" alt=""></span>
        <div class="scnd-hover hidden">
          <h3>Sherwani</h3>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 no-padd01">
    <div class="products-inr">
      <div class="row no-margin">
        <ul>
          <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="products-sm">
              <span id="box20-img-editor"><img src="/public/images/index_box20.png" alt=""></span>
              <div class="hover-div">
                <div class="hover-inr">
                  <h4>
                    <a href="#" id="main_img25_title-text-editor"> </a>
                  </h4>
                  <!-- <h5>Premium Collection</h5>
                                                <p><img src="/public/images/star.png" alt="" /></p> -->
                  <p id="main_img26_title-text-editor">£ </p>
                  <a id="header_cart13-link-editor" class="btn" href="http://www.google.com"> + add to cart</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="products-sm">
              <span id="box21-img-editor"><img src="/public/images/index_box21.png" alt=""></span>
              <div class="hover-div">
                <div class="hover-inr">
                  <h4>
                    <a href="#" id="main_img27_title-text-editor"> </a>
                  </h4>
                  <!-- <h5>Premium Collection</h5>
                                            <p><img src="/public/images/star.png" alt="" /></p> -->
                  <p id="main_img28_title-text-editor">£ </p>
                  <a id="header_cart14-link-editor" class="btn" href="http://www.google.com"> + add to cart</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="products-sm">
              <span id="box22-img-editor"><img src="/public/images/index_box22.png" alt=""></span>
              <div class="hover-div ">
                <div class="hover-inr">
                  <h4>
                    <a href="#" id="main_img29_title-text-editor"> </a>
                  </h4>
                  <!-- <h5>Premium Collection</h5>
                                            <p><img src="/public/images/star.png" alt="" /></p> -->
                  <p id="main_img30_title-text-editor">£ </p>
                  <a id="header_cart15-link-editor" class="btn" href="http://www.google.com"> + add to cart</a>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="products-sm">
              <span id="box23-img-editor"><img src="/public/images/index_box23.png" alt=""></span>
              <div class="hover-div">
                <div class="hover-inr">
                  <h4>
                    <a href="#" id="main_img31_title-text-editor"> </a>
                  </h4>
                  <!-- <h5>Premium Collection</h5>
                                                <p><img src="/public/images/star.png" alt="" /></p> -->
                  <p id="main_img32_title-text-editor">£ </p>
                  <a id="header_cart16-link-editor" class="btn" href="http://www.google.com"> + add to cart</a>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i set the max-height and max-width of parent div and same for the child div but when i zoom out the screen the images stretch.

if i fix the height on normal screen, it is ok. On zoom out its height is extra ordinary large.

I also use the media queries for all screen sizes.

can you help me to adjust the height of the images without stretching on all screen, including zoomout?

Comment: This is more complex, you would need a `responsive` design

Comment: if i give u the screen shot of the page. is it easy to tell for u

Comment: if i give u the screen shot of the page. is it easy to tell for u. this the link plz check it then tell me. http://imageshack.com/i/poJSZPSlp

Comment: Can you add some fake image(with same size than yours) to your code to see behavior and stretching issue ? (you can use and link  fake image from lorempixel.com or dummyimage.com or any other of your choice) Did you consider object-fit ?

Comment: this the screen shot when the screen zoom out 0n 25% https://imageshack.com/i/pmF5lT5Bp.  screen zoom out 0n 33% https://imageshack.com/i/pnryDB5Op, screen zoom out 0n 50%https://imageshack.com/i/poJFZlKap, screen zoom out 0n 99% and 100% https://imageshack.com/i/pnuOv5PLp

Comment: tell me if u find some solution about it